# Where to find TensorFlow 1.x Documentation

Tags: tensorflow

Where is the original TensorFlow 1 documentation? Not just of the API, but also guides and tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/master/site/en/r1) on GitHub.